# How to optimize count of new posts in favorites

Tags: sql, optimization, bookmarks, favorites

I would like to say, that I will be glad for any reply. I will try to structure my text for better understanding.

**Situation**
I run thematic internet forum, where you can add topics as your favorites in the menu and the menu shows the number of new posts in these topics. So everytime you reload the page (go anywhere on the whole site), new posts for all topics in your favorites are checked.

**Problem**
This is of course quite expensive on DB, because it is common to have 20-50 favorites and I have to check the DB if any post was added in any of these topics. The average topic has 1000-2000 posts. And this happens for every pageview for every user which is approximately 900 000 pageviews per month.

**Possible solution 1**
I store number of total posts in every topic and I store number of last viewed posts for every topic, for every user. This may be fastest, but it has a lot of disadvantages, which are functional (deleting, filtering of posts, etc.).

**Possible solution 2**
I store id of last viewed post for every topic, for every user. This is very good solution, but about ten times slower then previous one.

**Database**
I store all posts for all topics in one huge table = hunderds of thousands of posts.

**Question**
I would like to remove problems that brings solution 1, but I need to keep the speed. I thought of creating a table for each topic and use Solution 2, but I dont know if it will help. So if you have any experiences please just tell me what would be the fastest solution.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Firsty: No idea about your schema or database system, but this should be relativly simple assuming you keep a record of when your user was last seen ($DATE_USER_WAS_LAST_SEEN in the example below) and each of your posts is presumably associaed with it's topic by some kind of id and you have a list of all the $FAVOURITE ids.

```
SELECT topic_id, count(*) AS count FROM posts 
WHERE topic_id IN ($FAVOURITES) 
    AND created_date > $DATE_USER_WAS_LAST_SEEN 
GROUP BY topic_id
```

will give you an output like:

```
topic_id   |   count
---------------------
  3        |     20
  1        |     27
  33       |     120
```

This should be an acceptable speed for this kind of scale, you could improve the query by not using `IN` and making a long `(topic_id = 1 OR topic_id = 2 OR topic_id = etc)` string if your database doesn't automatically optimise these things.

Secondly: Don't worry so much about keeping these values bang up to date. People will use them as an indicator that there are new messages, not base life decisions on them, so cache these requests per user (either on the user's own record or using some kind of in-memory cache like memcache if you are familiar with those) and expire the cache every 5mins or so, this will radically reduce your hits to the database

Comment: Hi, thanks. This brought me one idea. This solution is in basic the same with the id solution, but I realized, that I didn't revisited all the favorites before testing so I had about 1000 new posts in every favorite, which may caused the slowliness. So one more question, to be sure. When I will have only 10 new posts, will be the count(id) faster?

Comment: The issue with both your solutions is that they require that you *write* to the database on every post-viewing. Writes are slow, reads are fast. So by estimating the last time you saw the user and using that to calculate the number of posts since they last visited, you save on a large number of writes to your db. If you have setup indexies for created_date and topic_id count() will be as fast as it can be. By using group you save the overhead of making multiple requests to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your post ids are sequential and always incrementing.

Create a table for your favorite with at least these fields : user_id, topic_id, last_post_id

You can then check for new posts with this simple query :

```
select topics.id, count(posts.id)
from users
inner join favorites on favorites.user_id = users.id
inner join topics on topics.id = favorites.topic_id
inner join posts on 
    posts.topic_id = topics.id and
    posts.id > last_post_id
where users.id = $id
group by topics.id
```

This should run pretty smoothly.

You must also update the last_post_id each time a user visit a topic, but this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I used similar query, but I didn't used group by. How does this effect the overall performance? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query with or without groub by will run at the same time. But if your indexes are setted right this should be really fast.

Answer (score 0):

I you have an index (topic_id, post_id) on the huge all_posts table it shouldn't be too costly to do this query:

```
select topic_id, count(*)
from all_posts a
inner join user_favorites u on u.topic_id = a.topic_id
where a.post_id > u.post_id and u.user_id = @user_id
group by topic_id
```